# How to generate numbers within a starting and ending range?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a starting range and ending range, and I need to be able to generate numbers withing this range, and increment the returned number by the start range + 1 every time, but never generate the same number twice.

Not sure how to do this with C#, any help would be great.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "increment the returned number by the start range + 1"? Does that mean that if the range was from 5 to 10 you'd add (5 + 1) to whatever number you generated?

Comment: what's the context here?  surely you already know how to define an integer and ++ it.  you haven't explained what in your particular situation makes this non-trivial...

Comment: The question is not clear at all. Don't understand what you need.

Comment: @BryanRoss he didn't mention randomness at all

Comment: @RobertLevy: True, but it sure sounds like that's what he means, with "generate numbers within range" and "never generate the same number twice"

Comment: @BryanRoss  sounds like static `int i = RANGE_START;  return i++;` to me

Comment: `foreach(int number in Enumerable.Range(start, end - start))`

Answer (score 3):

Try `Enumerable.Range(start, count)`. It's built-in to the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you just looking for an enumerable generator function?

```
public IEnumerable<int> Generate(int begin, int end) {
    int cur = begin;
    while(cur <= end) {
        yield return cur;
        cur++;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
foreach(int val in Generate(3, 15))
{
    DoWork(val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since its not entirely clear from your post, I will venture to guess that you want a function that when called gives you the next index (like an auto-incrementer that keeps track of the next value for you, as opposed to a list) -- the least verbose way is to use use a closure, I think:

```
        var closedIndex = new Func<int, int, Func<int>>((lower, upper) => {
            return delegate {
                if (lower < upper) {
                    lower++;
                    return lower;
                }
                return lower;                       
            };
        });
```

Usage:

```
        var nextIndex = closedIndex(1, 5);

        var first = nextIndex();
        var second = nextIndex();
        var third = nextIndex();

        Console.WriteLine(first);
        Console.WriteLine(second);
        Console.WriteLine(third);
```

Output is:

2

3

4

If thats not the intention, then John Weldons suggestion should work fine.